# Why does “Schweiz” form the corresponding adjective like a city?

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending, place-name

Is there a reason we say *Schweizer Schauspielerin* as opposed to *schweize Schauspielerin* (note lower case)? I believe this has to do with adjectives based on cities always being capitalized and ending with *-r* (e.g. *Berliner Mauer*). But why is a country-based adjective behaving that way?

Comment: Just to clarify: Could you explain how you'd derive the (invalid) adjective "schweize" from Schweiz? (I automatically read it as "schweizer", assuming you're just asking about lower/upper case)

Comment: Note that this phenomenon is not limited to *Schweiz,* but also applies to *Thüringen, Brandenburg, Tirol, Kärnten, Pfalz,* and many more.

Comment: As Mark Sitro commented, the adjective would be *schweizerisch*, which is used in the country name *Schweizerische Eidgenossenschaft* for example. Regarding *cities*: there are also the adjectives *hamburgisch*, *lübisch*, *köl(ni)sch* and *bremisch*, referring to cities [though probably in their capacity as countries], so the case is not that clear cut here, either.

Comment: Schweizer is a substantive. A (male) person from Schweiz. Something like schweizich oder schweizerich would be adjective, although I don't know if that is a real word.

Comment: Because _Schweiz_ is a proper noun, not an adjective. You can’t just add a case ending to a noun to make it an adjective. Conversely, _englisch_ and _deutsch_ are both adjectives, not proper nouns. Note how the corresponding names of the countries for those two are not _*English_ and _*Deutsch_, either, but are (originally) compounds/phrases with the noun _Land_ as their heads: _Deutschland_ is ‘German land’; _England_ (from earlier _Englaland_) is ‘land **of** the Angles’. _Schweiz_ is completely incomparable to these two.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The origin of the name "Schweiz" is indeed the name of the *town* "Schwyz" and the canton with the same name.

In the 14th century the Swiss people were actually called "Eidgenossen". After a battle (Schlacht bei Sempach) where soldiers from the canton "Schwyz" had an important part, a chronicler first called all "Eidgenossen" as "Schwyzer", short for "Schweizer Eidgenossen". And in the following centuries this name pushed through.

And that's why we have today

> deutsche Schauspielerin
>   englische Schauspielerin

but

> Schweizer Schauspielerin

Comment: Wir haben aber auch  
einen englischen Schauspieler aber eine englische Schauspielerin  
aber schweizerische Schauspielerin ist auch möglich.

Comment: Wir sagen auch Nürnberger Bratwürste, die nur in Nürnberg hergestellt werden. Aber Bratwürste aus Franken werden fränkische Bratwürste genannt.

Answer (score 9):

[**This rule**](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#K90) actually refers to "geographical names" rather than just cities - the capitalisation of "Schweizer" thus just follows the rules :)

> D 90:
>
> 1. Von geografischen Namen abgeleitete Wörter auf -er schreibt man immer groß <§ 61>.
>
>    das Ulmer Münster
>      eine Kölner Firma
>      die Schweizer Uhrenindustrie
>      die Wiener Kaffeehäuser

Edit: I apparently misunderstood the question at first.
If it is indeed primarily concerned with why the "-er" derivation isn't restricted to cities' names, I'm afraid there's probably no firm rule. You'll just have to memorise the rather few instances.

Speculation: There *might* be a tendency for this derivation in the alpine regions:

Tirol -> Tiroler Berge
Allgäu -> Allgäuer Kässpätzle
Vorarlberg -> Vorarlberger Skilehrer
Schwarzwald -> Schwarzwälder Kuckucksuhren

but also:
Thüringen -> Thüringer Rostbratwurst (although "thüringisch" is used for everything else besides these sausages)

Comment: I think the OP's question is why it is "deutsch**e** Schauspielerin", "englisch**e** Schauspielerin" but "Schweiz**er** Schauspielerin".

Comment: So the answer is: "deutsch" and "englisch" weren't derived from a geographical name, i.e. do not consist of such a name + "-er". A Deutscher would be someone from Deutsch, but Deutsch is not a place.

Comment: It's not speculation/tendency, it is as it is. deutsch and englisch are just adjectives. Tiroler is "${NAMEOFSOMETHING}er" - different rule.

Comment: I doubt your speculation concerning the alpine region, see Sylter Deich, Harzer Käse (as well as Tilsit-er, Edam-er).

Comment: @guidot Not to mention Engilsh _London-er_, _Dublin-er_, Danish _København-er_, Swedish _Stockholm-are_, Norwegian _Ålesund-er_, etc. Not only is it not limited to the Alpine region, it’s not limited to German at all—it’s common to nearly all Germanic languages. (Except maybe Icelandic; can’t think of any there.)

Comment: @guidot: Good point regarding Sylt and esp. Harz (as a relatively small island, Sylt could be argued to fall into the "city" category rather than "country" or "region" -- at least size-wise). Tilsit and Edam are in fact cities, so they don't really serve the point here, right?

Answer (score 5):

Today, Schweizer is considered an adjective. However it does not possess any declension which points to its actual origin being a genitive plural of the noun Schweizer. This also is the reason why it is still capitalized. Thus Schweizer Schauspielerin actually meant "(der Schweizer) Schauspielerin" thus "Schauspielerin von den Schweizern".

Knowing this, it is helpful for writing fluid German to avoid ambiguities that may reactivate the original genitive. Thus writing "... der Schweizer Schauspielerin" is harder to read, as "der" may be genitive plural or genitive/dativ singular.

Within Switzerland, the adjective schweizerisch is preferred to Schweizer. The official name of Switzerland is Schweizerische Eidgenossenschaft.  Similarly
[Schweizerische Normen-Vereinigung](https://www.snv.ch/) and not the Schweizer one &ct.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not enough rep to comment. I think you can say "deutsche" und "englische" because it already ends with a "sch". "Schweiz" does not end with "sch" so it's not possible.

You could use "schweizerische Schauspielerin" which seems to be also correct. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schweizerisch

Comment: No, that is not the reason. A town like Windisch would lead to "Windischer Berge" (no idea if there is a town by that name, or if there are mountains around ;) ).

Comment: There is a town called Windisch: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windisch_AG :P

Answer (score -1):

Simple: If something is directly Made Up from a place Name, Like Schweizer from Schweiz, it's **er**, If it's Not, Like deutsche from deutsch (deutsch ist an adjective, Not a place), it's **e**

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to say. Can you edit your answer and clarify it?

Comment: @Robert Ok, I Hope ist's okay now