# Wie erklärt sich die Bildung von geographischen Adjektiven wie »Schweizer«?

Tags: etymology, adjective, place-name

Es ist recht bekannt, dass sich das geographische Adjektiv *Schweizer* ganz anders als zum Beispiel *deutscher, französischer* oder *italienischer* verhält: Es wird großgeschrieben und es ist unveränderlich (»Trifft eine Schweizer Kuh eine deutsche Kuh …«). Darin ähnelt es Adjektiven, wie sie in der Regel von Städten gebildet werden *(Münchner U-Bahn, Kölner Stadtarchiv).* In allen mir bekannten Fällen gibt es auch ein »sich normal verhaltendes« Adjektiv, meistens auf *-isch.*

(Von den Adjektiven sind natürlich die gleichlautenden Substantive zu unterscheiden, die einen Einwohner desjenigen Gebiets bezeichnen. Diese sind nicht Bestandteil dieser Frage, es sei denn, sie sind zur Erklärung wichtig.)

Was genau ist die Herkunft von Formen wie *Schweizer;* wie wurden sie zum Adjektiv und warum sind sie unveränderlich und werden großgeschrieben?

Comment: Wir hatten das kürzlich. Es gibt eine Rechtschreibregel (§61), dass alle "Ableitungen von geografischen Eigennamen", die auf "-er" enden, groß geschrieben werden. Damit müsste man "Italienischer Expresso" auch groß schreiben.

Comment: @tofro [Meinst du das hier?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/40446) Da wird aber nicht nach der Herkunft gefragt, soweit ich das erkennen kann.

Comment: Ja - Es ist ein *ähnliches* Thema. Kein Duplikat.

Comment: @tofro Die meisten der entsprechenden Adjektive haben eine Form, die auf "-er" endet: "deutsch" => "deutsch**er** Wein". Die Regel bezieht sich wohl nur auf diejenigen Ableitungen aus geographischen Begriffen, die prinzipiell nur eine Form haben.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Du hast, glaube ich, recht - Bloß steht das nicht in der Regel.

Comment: @tofro Das muss wohl auch nicht unbedingt in der Regel stehen: Die Grundform des Adjektives "schön/-er/-es/-e" ist "schön" und nicht "schöner". Von daher wird der Schreiber der Regel implizit davon ausgehen, dass sich "deutscher" von "deutsch" ableitet und "deutsch" (ohne "-er") von "Deutschland".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ursprung dieser Bildung sind Personenbezeichnungen, z.B. *Schweizer* (gebildet mit derselben Endung, die auch in Wörtern wie *Reiter* oder *Schreiber* verwendet wird). Das Adjektiv geht auf den Genitiv plural «(der) Schweizer» zurück. Derartige Adjektive werden also deshalb nicht gebeugt, weil es sich um erstarrte Genitive handelt – und der Genitiv ist bereits ein Kasus und erhält keine weitere Kasus-Endung.

In der älteren Sprache konnte ein solcher Genitiv plural nicht nur vor, sondern auch nach dem Bezugswort auftreten, z.B. *zehen Regensburger schillinge* oder *zehen schillinge Regensburger,* vgl. [ER (DWB)](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=3,692,65).

Answer (score 1):

2 mögliche Erklärungen, die u.U. zusammenhängen:

Der Name der Schweiz wurde historisch abgeleitet vom Kanton *Schwyz*, der wiederum seinen Namen von der Gemeinde *Schwyz* bekommen hat. Es ist also nicht direkt ein Wunder, dass das zugehörige Adjektiv von der deutschen Sprache so behandelt wird wie ein Städtename. ("Die Schweiz ist ein Dorf").

Die Eigenschaft *Schweizer* hat es nie zu einem "richtigen" deklinierbaren Adjektiv geschafft, weil diese Position von dem Adjektiv *schweizerisch*, dass ein vollständig deklinierbares Adjektiv ist, schon belegt ist.

Das wirft natürlich weitere Fragen auf, wie z.B. warum es das Adjektiv *berlinerisch* erweiternd zur Eigenschaft *Berliner* (ähnlich zu *schweizerisch*) gibt, aber kein z.B. "soesterisch" (zumindestens wüsste ich nicht, dass es sowas gäbe) - Das führt aber hier zu weit, weil nicht Bestandteil der Frage.